# Can I use ECDSA address which is compatible with Ethereum as the Native address in a substrate based blockchain?

Tags: address, ecdsa, sr25519

For my project, I have to build a blockchain using ECDSA address in order to be compatible with Ethereum. But the native address is in sr25519 scheme in substrate. What should I do to implement this? Are there any best practices?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK substrate supports a couple of signature schemes, among them secp256k1. Moonbeam is a chain built with substrate which uses Ethereum-compatible [unified accounts](https://docs.moonbeam.network/learn/features/unified-accounts/). I suggest looking at their docs and/or code for more detailed information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Does it mean I have to do some "Deep customization" to substrate except only coding for a pallet?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's very 'deep customization'. Please have a look at [this code](https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/blob/master/primitives/account/src/lib.rs) in the Moonbeam repository. This is how the 'unified accounts' are implemented.